# Why Asp.net MVC4 can not use the cookieless of SQL Server Session state storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, session-state, session-cookies

ALL, Here is my web config in a Asp.net MVC4 application. I found if I set cookieless false ,everything goes fine. but If I don't want use cookie . then the application can not work.when I debug the application, I found the controller can not receive any request from the view. I think It is because when in the cookie-less mode, Something would be appended to the url before . like http:/ /localhost:8119/(S(3cicpjpagvpunr5he5fnfrj1))/.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="webAssets" type="Telerik.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebAssetConfigurationSection, Telerik.Web.Mvc" requirePermission="false" />
      <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
      <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="..." connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="14400" maxRequestLength="716800" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!-- <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState> -->
    <sessionState mode="SQLServer" cookieless="true" sqlConnectionString="data source=xxxx; User ID=xxxx; password=xxxx" timeout="300" sqlCommandTimeout="10" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="asset.axd" validate="false" type="Telerik.Web.Mvc.WebAssetHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.Mvc" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="3000000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="asset" />
      <add name="asset" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="asset.axd" type="Telerik.Web.Mvc.WebAssetHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.Mvc" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.7.0.0" newVersion="1.7.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a bug in the `Html.BeginForm()` helper (the one that doesn't take any arguments) when used with `cookieless="true"`. It doesn't take into account the session id when generating the url. So instead of:

```
<form action="/(S(kkt0zgbnuaoxad23ew33iod4))/home/index" method="post">
```

it generates:

```
<form action="/home/index" method="post">
```

When you post to `/home/index` a redirect is automatically made to `/(S(kkt0zgbnuaoxad23ew33iod4))` by ASP.NET. A redirect means a GET request => your POST action will never be hit.

As a workaround you could write a custom `Html.BeginForm` helper to fix the bug:

```
public static class FormExtensions
{
    public static IDisposable MyBeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        var rawUrl = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
        var formAction = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("~/") + rawUrl;
        var builder = new TagBuilder("form");
        builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary());
        builder.MergeAttribute("action", formAction);
        builder.MergeAttribute("method", HtmlHelper.GetFormMethodString(FormMethod.Post), true);
        htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
        var form = new MvcForm(htmlHelper.ViewContext);
        return form;
    }
}
```

and then use:

```
@using (Html.MyBeginForm())
{
    ...
}
```

As far as the other overloads of the BeginForm helper are concerned, they should work fine and generate proper action containing the session id.

Comment: Could u please help to review my [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995415/why-did-not-redirect-to-view-in-asp-net-mvc-4) ?thanks