# TempData with cookies disabled

Tags: c#, tempdata

Is it possible to use TempData when cookies are disabled? I have a redirect check that depends on a TempData key, but when cookies are disabled, that key is always null.

Comment: TempData is much like Session in so much it uses cookies by default. You can configure asp.net to use cookieless sessions. It will I think put that data in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TempData is a way to [persist something between HTTP requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Because HTTP is inherently stateless, you can't persist something without having a way to identify the client.

TempData [uses the Session as storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004081/where-does-tempdata-get-stored), which by default uses cookies to persist a user's session between HTTP requests. A cookie is included in every request with a key to that particular user's session.

If you want TempData to work without cookies, you can set the `cookieless="true"` attribute of the `sessionState` tag in your web.config file. That appends a query string parameter to every link in your site to achieve the same result. However, it's [not recommended](http://brockallen.com/2012/04/08/cookieless-session-considered-dangerous/) and you will have [issues if you're using MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994772/why-asp-net-mvc4-can-not-use-the-cookieless-of-sql-server-session-state-storage).

If you want it to work without using cookies, include a query string parameter on the target URL instead if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the `TempDataProvider` of the `Controller`. the default provider is `SessionStateTempDataProvider` which relies on the regular Session State Storage.

That basically means that if Cookies are disabled, you won't have neither `Session` or `TempData` unless you'll implement [Cookie-less Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx).